# Change multiple named cells and ranges in a worksheet at once

Tags: excel, rename, vba

I want to change a lot of excell names in a worksheet (200+), names are like comp.... and I want to change it in cons.... . So every time is the change the same. Is there a way to do this all at once?

I know for functions it is simple using control h and then replace comp with cons and then they will all change at once. Do you also know whether this is possible for names (so the names of cells and range of cells). It will save me a lot of (especially boring) work. Thanks a lot already!

Best
Timothy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If you know* [How to use Excel Macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx),

```
Sub RangeRename()
 Dim N As Name
    For Each N In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        N.Name = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(N.Name, "comp", "cons")
    Next N
End Sub
```

*If not*

1. Hit `Alt+F11`
2. Paste the code from above
3. Hit `F5`->`Run`

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it worked great! It saved me many hours! The only mistake (which I made) was that the words are case sensitive so for people who want to use this answer as well, watch out for capitals as you have to include them! Thanks again!