# excel update reference for named cells and ranges using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a script in excel vba to change the Reference of a bunch of defined names.  I have a revised workbook with updated data and a new name; I would want to change each defined name reference to the updated workbook.  For example:

change the reference of the named range

from  `'[c:\files\[factorsrev1.xls]'!:$K$15:$N$76`

to   `'[c:\files\[newfactorsrev2.xlsm]!:$K$15:$N$76`

I tried using the ([change-multiple-named-cells-and-ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141522/change-multiple-named-cells-and-ranges-in-a-worksheet-at-once)) post, as a guide, but so far it hasn't worked.

What I have so far:

```
Sub RangeRename()

  Dim N As Name

  For Each N In ActiveWorkbook.Names

    N.RefersTo = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(N.RefersTo, "factorsrev1.xls", "newfactorsrev2.xlsm")

  Next N

End Sub
```

Sure would be nice not having to edit each one manually...help is most appreciated.

Comment: Use `Name.Add` instead. It updates the names definition if ithe name aleady exists.

Comment: ok, great! Many thanks.